# fopen returns NULL when opening existing files in Linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, file-io

In my laboratory work I need to read data from 2 files and get a resulting file.
I tried using fopen for reading existing files and creating a new one.

```
FILE* file1 = fopen("1.txt", "r");
FILE* file2 = fopen("2.txt", "r");
FILE* fileRes = fopen("res.txt", "w");
```

Unfortunately, fopen for file1 and file2 returns NULL, even though fileRes was sucessfully opened. Futhermore, I can't read data from file1 and file2 which results in incorrect output.

Here is my directory:

[image]

As you can see files 1.txt and 2.txt are present in directory and file res.txt was sucessfully created.

All files have read/write permissions:

-rw-r--r-- 1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 2.txt
-rw-r--r-- res.txt

Comment: @anastaciu, these files are not any different from one another. I just need to use them in certain order. That's why I used digits instead of other names.

Comment: What is `errno` value after failure? You also can print corresponding error message with `perror()`.

Comment: @dimich, after fopen errno equals 0. When I try to read from this file errno equals 2 and prints "Error occurred while opening file. : Bad file descriptor"

Comment: @anastaciu, if I use "1.txt.txt" fopen also returns NULL.

Comment: @VeceluXa `errno` can't be 0 after `fopen()` return NULL. Please show complete code how do you check it for NULL and print errno value.

Comment: @anastaciu, If I change filename to something other than digits (like text_file.txt) fopen still returns NULL. Also removing .txt extension does not help either

Comment: @anastaciu, If I change filename to something other than digits (like text_file.txt) fopen still returns NULL. Also removing .txt extension does not help either

Comment: @dimich, 
`errno = 0;
FILE *file1 = fopen("text_file", "r");
printf("%s", strerror(errno));`
With this code strerror(errno) prints nothing. When I try to read from file before strerror I get "Error occurred while opening file. : Bad file descriptor"

Comment: @VeceluXa But how do you know `file1` is NULL? What code does check it?

Comment: @dimich I check it in gdb debugger using vscode.

Comment: @VeceluXa can you print it in runtime? E.g. `printf("%p\n", (void *)file1)` right after `fopen()`?

Comment: @anastaciu, I managed to write "String" in my result file using fputs.

Comment: @dimich, well, it's strange. In runtime this line printed random address (0x5653c13806d0), but while debugging it prints "(nil)".

Comment: @VeceluXa It means fopen succeed and return not NULL. Something wrong happens later. Hard to say not seeing full code. With debugger, it may be optimized out if you compile with optimization enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Actually fopen was working just fine. NULL was showing in my **debugger** (gdb in vscode), while in runtime `printf("%p\n", (void *)file1)` printed some random address in memory.